# Bash script to copy files from one folder to another

Tags: bash

I have a folder, `A`, that contains around 100 subfolders, `Asub1`,`Asub2`, etc.  I am trying to go into each `Asub` folder, and copy two files back to the `A` folder.  I have the following code:

```
for D in `find . -type d`
do
    cd $D
    cp log_* ../
    cp *.pdf ../
    cd ../
done
```

However this result in the following error for each sub folder:

```
cp: cannot stat `log_*': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `*.pdf': No such file or directory
```

Could someone please tell me where I am going wrong in my code?

Comment: a simpler way is to `cd` into `A` folder (`cd A`) and then do `cp ./*/log_* ./*/*.pdf .`

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: @IcedCoffee then please select the person's answer as the correct one.  it will show that no one else needs to help.

Comment: A simpler way is to not cd anywhere and just use `find`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler way is to `cd` into `A` folder (`cd A`) and then do:

```
cp */log_* */*.pdf .
```